# Jinja2 Space in variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
       "custom_fields": {
        "Datacentre Code": "p", 
        "Region": "EU"
    },
```

I have the data format above, and I want to access the "Datacentre code" and return the result.

To access the Region I run the below command

```
{% set Region = item.resultDC.custom_fields.Region %}
```

To access the DC code I am running the below command

```
{% set DCCode= item.resultDC.custom_fields.Datacentre Code %}
```

This gives me the following error, how do I get this variable

```
AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'Code
```

Comment: Why don't you try with `{% set Code=item.resultDC.custom_fields.Datacentre %}`

Comment: This does not work and gives me the error  AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'Datacentre'"}. So I need to specify the full name but I am unsure how to with the spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can use the syntax  `item.resultDC.custom_fields['Datacentre Code']` to access properties of a dict like that.